# How did stuntman Mike evade the police after the murders?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-proof

[**Spoiler alert**] In Quentin Tarantino's movie, "Deathproof", the villain *Stuntman Mike* murders the four girls in a car accident by riding the car in wrong way.

The four girls die, but he survives with minor injuries because of his stunt car.

I didn't get the part where the police leave him with no charge even when he had rode the car in the wrong path and straight into those girls' car. How did he evade it so easily?

EDIT:

If someone's interested, watch the murder scene on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvgRUa41ULQ) [**Warning: Graphic**].

Comment: How would the police know *he* drove into the wrong path? All the witnesses are dead.

Comment: @Walt yeah all witnesses are dead but couldn't the police can easily say that the guy rode the car in wrong path and hit them hard, through their investigation? and also leaving with no charge looks a bit awkward to me..

Comment: You felt the need to warn us that a Tarantino's murder scene is graphic? Even Tarantino's burger eating scenes are graphic.

Comment: @corsiKa haha yeah.. Walt had added that "Graphic" text :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It could be argued that the explanation isn't sufficient but it **is** in the film, in the conversation between the Ranger and Son No. 1:

> -Well, what are you gonna do?
>
> -Not a goddamn thing. **D.A. says there ain't no crime here. Every one of them gals was swimming in alcohol and floatin' on weed, and old Hooper in there came out clean as a whistle.**
>
> -Now, you actually think that he premeditatively murdered them gals?
>
> -**Well, I can't prove it.**
>
> [...]
>
> Yeah, I think the only thing we can dream of getting that bastard on
>   is vehicular manslaughter for the hitchhiker in the death box. That was just plain old, goddamn reckless endangerment. But I got me a goddamn bartender
>   gonna testify that ol' Stuntman Mike didn't drink a drop all night. And his passenger was left stranded by her date, in the goddamn rain, no less,
>   and she asked him for the fucking ride. Now, **on paper, this is gonna look
>   like he was just trying to help her out. I mean, that's the way the jury's gonna see it.**
>
> -So, what are you gonna do, Pop?
>
> -Well, I could take it upon myself to work the case, Search for evidence,
>   you know, prove my theory. Alert authorities. Dog that rotten son of a bitch. Wherever he goes, I go. Or **I could spend the same goddamn amount of time and energy following the NASCAR circuit.**

Seeing that Mike was sober and the girls weren't, and this happened at night on a deserted road and all other witnesses are dead, the police suspects Mike but concludes that there's no case.

Comment: +1 i believe he also adds that if he commits that crime anywhere in the same state again he would arrest him too.